# How to run this compiled open MPI program (C)?

Tags: c, mpi

I am trying to run the example code at the following url. I compiled the program with "mpicc twoGroups.c" and tried to run it as "./a.out", but got the following message: Must specify MP_PROCS= 8. Terminating.

**My question is how do you set MP_PROCS=8 ?**

Group and Communication Routine examples at here https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/mpi/

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#define NPROCS 8

main(int argc, char *argv[])  {
int        rank, new_rank, sendbuf, recvbuf, numtasks,
           ranks1[4]={0,1,2,3}, ranks2[4]={4,5,6,7};
MPI_Group  orig_group, new_group;
MPI_Comm   new_comm;

MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numtasks);

if (numtasks != NPROCS) {
  printf("Must specify MP_PROCS= %d. Terminating.\n",NPROCS);
  MPI_Finalize();
  exit(0);
  }

sendbuf = rank;

/* Extract the original group handle */
MPI_Comm_group(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &orig_group);

/* Divide tasks into two distinct groups based upon rank */
if (rank < NPROCS/2) {
  MPI_Group_incl(orig_group, NPROCS/2, ranks1, &new_group);
  }
else {
  MPI_Group_incl(orig_group, NPROCS/2, ranks2, &new_group);
  }

/* Create new new communicator and then perform collective communications */
MPI_Comm_create(MPI_COMM_WORLD, new_group, &new_comm);
MPI_Allreduce(&sendbuf, &recvbuf, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, new_comm);

MPI_Group_rank (new_group, &new_rank);
printf("rank= %d newrank= %d recvbuf= %d\n",rank,new_rank,recvbuf);

MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Comment: Google returned this: [Set the MP_PROCS Environment Variable](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/clresctr/vxrx/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.cluster.pe.v1r3.pe100.doc%2Fam102_mpp.htm).

Comment: have you tried `mpirun -n <# of processes> ./myprog`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you execute an MPI program, you need to use the appropriate wrappers. Most of the time it looks like this:

```
mpiexec -n <number_of_processes> <executable_name> <executable_args>
```

So for your simple example:

```
mpiexec -n 8 ./a.out
```

You will also see `mpirun` used instead of `mpiexec` or `-np` instead of `-n`. Both are fine most of the time.

If you're just starting out, it would also be a good idea to make sure you're using a recent version of MPI so you don't get old bugs or weird execution environments. MPICH and Open MPI are the two most popular implementations. MPICH just released version 3.1 available [here](http://www.mpich.org/downloads) while Open MPI has version 1.7.4 available [here](http://www.open-mpi.org/software/ompi/v1.7/). You can also usually get either of them via your friendly neighborhood package manager.